# Example of a connected semi-Riemannian manifold

Tags: semi-riemannian-geometry

Give an example of a connected [semi-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) that is complete at one point but not complete.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @Pp.. As you very well know, this kind of posing as the OP is *very* controversial to say the least. *If* you are going to do it,   please identify yourself in the comments or otherwise and do not put words in OP's mouth.

Comment: I think this is true but I need another example.